# How to negate regex with lookarounds

Tags: objective-c, regex, sqlite, regex-negation

I have a regex-expression

```
(?<=@)'|'(?=%)
```

It successfully matches any apostrophe that is placed around `%@` in this objective-c string

```
@"UPDATE RESTAURANTS SET CITY='%@', NAME='%@' ", city, @"Joy's Restaurant";
```

But I want the opposite thing, to match any apostrophe that is NOT around `%@` i.e. to only match the apostrophe in `Joy's Restaurant` in this example.

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Just as an aside, I'm not sure if this is your goal here, but it seems like it would be much easier (and safer) to parameterize your SQL query.

Comment: Just get rid of the |:   `(?<!@)'(?!%)` http://regex101.com/r/wL0uT9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Negative lookarounds are pretty straight forward. Use `(?!…)` for a negative lookahead and `(?<!…)` for a negative lookbehind. For example:

```
(?<!@)'(?!%)
```

Will match any apostrophe so long as it is not immediately preceded by a `@` and it is not followed by a `%`. Notice that you have to remove the alternation (`|`) as you want to make sure that *both* lookarounds are satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

Use a **Negative Lookbehind** and **Negative Lookahead** instead.

```
(?<!@)'(?!%)
```

[**Live Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/vC8fU1)

Alternatively you can use the alternation operator in context placing what you want to exclude on the left, ( *saying throw this away, it's garbage* ) and place what you want to match in a capturing group on the right side.

```
'%@'|(')
```

[**Live Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/mY8wW3)